# Flutter - Iterar array en un mapa

Tags: map, flutter

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil con Flutter. Todo va en principio bien, pero necesito implementar un mapa. Dado que Google aún no ha desarrollado un paquete estable estoy usando flutter_map que usa Leaflet.

Consigo pintar un mapa, pero el problema viene cuando intento pintar un array. Actualmente tengo esto.

```
 MapController mapController;
  Map<String, LatLng> coords;
  List<Marker> markers;
  List<Map<String, LatLng>> listado = [];

  Future<Null> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    for (Map user in responseJson) {
      coords.putIfAbsent("Test", () => new LatLng(user['lat'], user['long']));
      listado.add(coords);
     // print(listado.toList());
    }
  }

 void initState() {
super.initState();
mapController = new MapController();
coords = new Map<String, LatLng>();
fetchPost().then((data) {
  print(data);
  for (int i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
    markers.add(new Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: coords.values.elementAt(i),
        builder: (ctx) => new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])));
  }
});
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterMap(
      options: new MapOptions(
        center: new LatLng(37.7525244, 139.1650556),
        zoom: 5.0,
      ),
      mapController: mapController,
      layers: [
        new TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
        new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
      ],
    );
  }
}

final String url =
    'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tobiobi/myjasonserver/coordinates';

//STATES
class UserDetails {
  final String name;
  final double lat, long;

  UserDetails({this.name, this.lat, this.long});

  factory UserDetails.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return new UserDetails(
      name: json['name'],
      lat: json['lat'],
      long: json['long'],
    );
  }
}
```

Me retorna

> But return 'the getter iterator was called on null'. The data has this
>   json

Es decir, a la hora de hacer el *for* falla porque *listado.length* está vacío. Obviamente todo eso ocurre porque en el *then* el *data* no llega, sin embargo el array listado en el método *fetchPost()* si que tiene datos. Supongo que el problema está en ese método y en como retorno el listado. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servicio retorna un array no un map, por lo que debes iterar el array, puedes hacerlo así :

```
          Future<Null> fetchPost() async {
            list = List();
            markers = List();
            mapController = new MapController();
            coords = new Map<String, LatLng>();
            final response = await http.get(
                'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tobiobi/myjasonserver/coordinates');
            final List responseJson = json.decode(response.body) as List;
            for (Map<String, dynamic> data in responseJson) {
                    _counter++;
              coords.putIfAbsent("Test $_counter", () => new LatLng(double.parse(data['lat'].toString()),  double.parse(data['long'].toString())));
             print(coords);
             list.add(coords);
              // print(listado.toList());
            }
            return;
          }
```

Comment: Me devuelve "the name void isn´t a type so can´t be used as a type argument" :$

Comment: bueno, dejalo con el Null, ya lo actualicé

Answer (score 0):

investigando un poco a fondo encontre una solucion mas eficas con un futureBuiler.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _coordenadas.getCoordenadasPuntosTecnicos(),
        // initialData: [],
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return _mapa(snapshot.data);
        },
      ),
```

dentro del future llamo a la peticion https, en el builder evaluo la condición, cuando devulve la data de la solicitud la paso por parametro a un metodo que devuelve el widgets de mapas.

```
 Widget _mapa(data) {
    return FlutterMap(
      mapController: map,
      options: MapOptions(
        center: LatLng(-34.6624807, -58.5314526),
        zoom: 10.0,
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
          urlTemplate:
              "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/xxxxxxx/ckc6mvy5j166q1ipg31c1blu8/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={accessToken}",
          additionalOptions: {
            'accessToken':
                '{ <accessToken> }',
          },
        ),
        _marcadores(data)
      ],
    );
  }

  MarkerLayerOptions _marcadores(data) {
    return MarkerLayerOptions(markers: _buildMarkersOnMap(data));
  }

  List<Marker> _buildMarkersOnMap(data) {
    List<Marker> markers = List<Marker>();

    for (var item in data) {
      print(item.lat);
      Marker marker = Marker(
        point: LatLng(double.parse(item.lat), double.parse(item.lng)),
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        builder: (context) => Column(children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              size: 30.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 50.0,
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              item.direccion,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                  fontSize: 25.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(' Latitud: ' + item.lat),
                                Text(' Longitud: ' + item.lng),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
          ),
          Container(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 30.0,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(
                item.direccion,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      );
      markers.add(marker);
    }
    if (_currentPosition != null) {
      Marker marker2 = Marker(
          point: LatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude),
          height: 100.0,
          width: 100.0,
          builder: (context) => Column(children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.person_pin_circle,
                  size: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )
              ]));
      markers.add(marker2);
    }
    return markers;
  }
```

dentro del metodo "_buildMarkersOnMap(data)", la data que viene es la respuesta del snapshot( mi array de coordenadas ), y dentro del mismo realizo un "for" para reccorrer el array y crear los marcadores.